# How can you stop a sound from playing in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, playback

I have this code in the second frame to play a song, and it works fine. The class of the sound in my library being "MySound".

```
var snd:MySound = new MySound
snd.play();
```

Now I need the song to stop playing from a latter frame.

Comment: @The_asMan [Sound](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html) does not implement `stop()`.

Answer (score 11):

You have to use `SoundChannel` class for this:

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("myFavSong.mp3"));
myChannel = mySound.play();

// ...

myChannel.stop();
```

Reference: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/ (Section 4 - *Stopping a Sound*)

Answer (score 1):

```
//*This code for playing the sound after import to the library*
var mySound:Sound = new MenuMusic(); 
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
myChannel = mySound.play();

//*This code for the nextframe button*
btn_easy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, btneasy);
function btneasy(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   gotoAndPlay(62);
   myChannel.stop();
}
```

*Reminder* :

> You don't have to drag the sound file to the timeline . Just paste the
>   code to the designated Action Script of the button.

```
var mySound:Sound = new MenuMusic();
```

> 'MenuMusic' can be changed what you want. Just Right click the sound
>   file in the library then select Properties . Click ActionScript Tab and
>   check 'Export for ActionScript' and you can now changed the name in
>   'Class' Input Box..

It works so fine to me :)

Hope it solved the problem ! :D