# How do I stop sound using AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

> my sounds in code called sound1 , sound2 my sounds in class called sounda , soundb I hope find answers to fix my problem`

```
    import flash.events.Event;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

stop();

var sound1:sounda = new sounda();
var sound2:soundb = new soundb();

cbox.addItem( { label: "chose"} )
cbox.addItem( { label: "first"} )
cbox.addItem( { label: "sec"}   )

cbox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,plays);

function plays(e:Event):void
{
    if (cbox.selectedItem.label == "first") 
    {
        sound1.play();
           //not working
        sound2.stop();
    } 




    if (cbox.selectedItem.label == "sec") 

    {
        sound2.play();
        //not working
        sound1.stop();
    }
    }
```

//when I play sound1 then when I play sound2 .. sound1 still playing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you stop a sound from playing in as3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421939/how-can-you-stop-a-sound-from-playing-in-as3)

Answer (score 1):

to stop all sounds from playing

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
SoundMixer.stopAll();
```

to stop a single sound, you must using `SoundChannel`

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("myFavSong.mp3"));
myChannel = mySound.play();

// ...

myChannel.stop();
```